# Root not able to login to remote host, other users are

Tags: ssh, remote-access, login, ubuntu-18.04

All was ok. I could login as a normal user or root, thru SSH method or password, on FTP or Bash/Terminal (on Win10 pc).

Then today I was working on some wordpress permissions.
Then I found that nginx wasn’t starting upon droplet/server reboot.
Today I was working on some user's permissions, nothing big, and at last gave an nginx commands (mainly:  “sudo update-rc.d nginx enable”) and rebooted.

But after that, I’m no longer able to login as root over FTP or Bash Terminal. Thru ssh keys method or password.
Error comes: “Permission Denied. Pls try again”.
Although, I’m able to login as root in console, with the same root’s password.
And I’m able to login in FTP or Bash as another user.
Also I’m able to login as root in another droplet with the same ssh keys which are already uploaded in my DO control panel and whose pvt keys are lying there in my same local pc.

That is/The scene becomes:
pvt keys on my local pc and public keys on remote host are ok, because I’m able to login to another droplet on the same DO account.

Root pw is ok, because the same pw is working thru console. (moreover, when I login as another user in bash, then inside there I switch to root, then the same root password works and I become root there).

sshd_config files all options seem to be ok, because I can login as another user (and I’ve checked all 3-4 relevant options manually also).

Kindly help.
I’m just striking my head to the wall, but nothing is coming to mind.

Comment: Did the **PermitRootLogin yes** option get changed? Did the ssh server get upgraded - maybe the defaults replaced your sshd_config.

Comment: #PermitRootLogin yes. I've reloaded/restarted ssh(d) services and even rebooted the droplet also.

Comment: Remove the #, restart sshd.

Comment: Yeah, thank God, now I'm at least able to login as root by root pw. But how come this 'default' setting needs to be uncommented?
Did it have anything related to the 'Nginx command' I gave before rebooting the droplet?

Comment: Now, I'll go further and create new pvt/public keys and see why key method isn't working any more (perhaps, after this problem erupted yesterday, I happen to change keys, or did something).

Comment: My root folder on/of local win10's bash has 715 permission, its .ssh folder has 644 and id_rsa has 600 and id_rsa.pub has 755 permissions. Are these ok? When I try to connect to remote ubuntu host (till yesterday they're working ok, but since my trouble I've recreated them again and again a few times), I get the error: 'Permission Denied. Public key'.

Comment: Sorry, never used Nginx. I've never used Windows 10's bash, so I can't help you there, either. But the .ssh folder should not be readable by everyone.

Comment: Thanks very very much for enabling me to login as root by using pw. But after spending nearly half hour in regenerating key pairs, checking/restricting their permissions, I still can't login as root (in bash terminal) to remote host using open-ssh keys. Error: Permission denied (publickey). (That doesn't diminishes the help you provided).

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to part solve my problem (50%).
I wasn't able to login to my droplet as root (from Win10 Bash Terminal) either by ssh key or by pw.

But as @ajgringo619 suggested, there is one line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file in the remote server which by default is commented out and works in that way. But don't know the reason, now I had to uncomment that line, so that it became 'PermitRootLogin yes', and reload ssh service (on remote host).

So, now 50% part remained is why root is still not able to use ssh keys in local Bash for logging into remote Ubuntu host (all settings in remote sshd_config ok, permissions to .ssh folder, id_rsa and id_rsa.pub exactly as required). I even prepared a .ssh/config file containing a few recommened lines, but that gave another/more errors. So, removed that file and am still getting the error: Permission denied (publickey).
Note: I'm able to login as root in Sftp/FileZilla using putty ssh keys (idrsa.ppk)

Thanks again @ajgringo619

Comment: I later added my public key once again, carefully, in the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys remote host file, and voilla, that login problem over ssh keys too got solved. Thanks gusy. Without earlier solution by ajgringo619 this would never be possible.